# Blender 2.83 won't start in Mac os Catalina

Tags: installation, osx

Blender doesn't start and keeps jumping for about a minute and goes to not responding. I have tried reinstalling , updating my os and even installed python . It still won't open.

Comment: Check if your hardware and OS fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.8x. If it does you may want to follow [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports/173685#173685) to report a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall blender and remove all components related to blender in Finder.

Search for any files or folders with the program’s name or developer’s name in the ~/Library/Preferences/, ~/Library/Application Support/ and ~/Library/Caches/ folders. Right click on those items and click Move to Trash to delete them.